# UI-grid grouping auto expand

Tags: grouping, angular-ui-grid, expand

Does anybody know how to automatically expand a UI-grid that is performing a grouping? I need the grid to open up and start up with it being completely expanded.

Their API and Tutorial reference doesn't explain explicitly enough for me to understand.

My HTML div

```
<code>
&lt;div id="grid1" ui-grid="resultsGrid" class="myGrid" ui-grid-grouping&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
</code>
```

My Javascript

```
    
    $scope.resultsGrid = {
      ,columnDefs: [
      { field:'PhoneNum', name:'Phone'},
      { field:'Extension', name:'Extension'},
      { name:'FirstName'},
      { field:'DeptDesc', grouping: {groupPriority: 0}} 
      ]
    ,onRegisterApi: function(gridApi)
      {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

you just need to add

```
//expand all rows when loading the grid, otherwise it will only display the totals only
      $scope.gridApi.grid.registerDataChangeCallback(function() {
          $scope.gridApi.treeBase.expandAllRows();
        });
```

in your `onRegisterApi: function(gridApi)`that should be updated like this `onRegisterApi: function(gridApi)` so your function will be like this

```
$scope.resultsGrid.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {       
      //set gridApi on scope
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

      //expand all rows when loading the grid, otherwise it will only display the totals only
      $scope.gridApi.grid.registerDataChangeCallback(function() {
          $scope.gridApi.treeBase.expandAllRows();
        });
    };
```

or you can add botton to expand data like shown in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hW5cMgAqJWCzmuyNSnJH?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The closest analogy would the selection tutorial, in which we select the first row after the data finishes loading: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection

```
$http.get('/data/500_complex.json')
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    $timeout(function() {
      if($scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow){
        $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
      }
    });
  });
```

The key understanding is that you can't select (or expand) data that hasn't been loaded yet.  So you wait for the data to return from $http, then you give it to the grid, and you wait for 1 digest cycle for the grid to ingest the data and render it - this is what the $timeout does.  Then you can call the api to select (or in your case, expand) the data.

So for you, you'd probably have:

```
$http.get('/data/500_complex.json')
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    $timeout(function() {
      if($scope.gridApi.grouping.expandAllRows){
        $scope.gridApi.grouping.expandAllRows();
      }
    });
  });
```

If you're on the latest unstable, that call will change to `$scope.gridApi.treeBase.expandAllRows`.

Comment: Thanks that helped me so much!  I had to make a few changes but all in all, your help was awesome.

Comment: Ah, I see I left a spare selection in there.  You shouldn't need to add selection to make this work - but you may have needed to if you just copied and pasted my code, as I had selection instead of grouping.  Note my comment that the grouping api changes in the next RC

Comment: Ok I will make sure I make the change to treebase when the next RC is released.  The biggest thing that you helped me with was making sense of the API.  I'll be able to map out the api now.

Answer (score 0):

```
My Module - I had to add ui.gridl.selection
<pre>
<code>
angular.module('ddApp',['ngRoute','ngSanitize','ngCookies','ngResource','ui.grid.selection'])
</code>    
</pre>

My Controller - Amongh the other Dependency Injected items, I also had to add $timeout
<pre>
<code>
    .controller('myCtrl', function(`$`timeout)){}
</code>
</pre>


<pre>
<code>
$timeout(function(){
    if($scope.gridApi.grouping.expandAllRows){
       $scope.gridApi.grouping.expandAllRows();
    }
});
</code>
</pre>
```